# how to show all boot options and then hide them from rEFInd?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, startup, efi

I believe I have rEFInd running

When it’s active, refit and a duplicate windows partition show up.  (i have kali, windows 10, and OS X catalina) and then choose JUST those three to boot from, but there's two extra. a extra windows boot option, and the rEFIt

I don't want them there.

I cannot find rEFIt in libraries/startupitems there is NOTHING there, and don't know if its in EFI because nothing in there is names rEFIt, windows

Is there a way to see all bootable drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the current version of rEFInd installed, then you should be able to hide the undesired menu items by highlighting the icon and pressing the <kbd>-</kbd> key. This assumes `hidden_tags` appears as a `showtools` option parameter in the `refind.conf` file. See [Hiding and Displaying EFI Boot Loaders](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding) for more information.

If you have Hidden Tags enabled, then the following icon will appear on the tools line of rEFInd.

[image]

The default location for a rEFInd installation is the `EFI/refind` folder in the hidden `EFI` volume (`disk0s1`). You can mount this volume by using the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

You can unmount by using the command given below.

```
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

> Note: You mention rEFIt  in your question. You should not be using rEFIt with Catalina. The [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) Project is depreciated and has been replaced with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).